# Way to count number of hops between two nodes and to identify lowest nodes in a hierarchy graph

Tags: arangodb

I am relatively new to arangodb hence the below questions might be super easy to answer but I wasn't able to dig out the solution from the documentation yet.

**What I have:**

**1. Problem:** I have modelled a parent child hierarchy of items (nodes) that are linked by edges (isChildOf). The depth is unbalanced for the individual branches and can reach from say 1 over 1.1 to 1.1.1 and 1.1.1.1. Each hierarchy has a root node. Now I want to find out for a given child, e.g. one that is 1.1.1.1 how many edges away it is from the root node 1. So instead of setting the number of edges as a query filter parameter, I want to do the contrary and count the number of "hops" from e.g. 1 to 1.1.1.1 or from 1.1.1.1 to 1.1.1.1.5.2. How could I achieve this in AQL?

**2. Problem:** I am still looking for a way on how to retrieve the lowest nodes of a previously defined hierarchy (nodes which are not a parent of a child node). E.g. if the hierarchy ends at 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2.1 how can I retrieve all these lowest nodes in a AQL single query?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, depending on what you want to return (or how the queries are nested), but either way, either [`SHORTEST_PATH`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-shortest-path.html) or [`K_SHORTEST_PATHS`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-kshortest-paths.html) will be your friend.  Here is an example:

```
FOR v,e IN INBOUND SHORTEST_PATH start_node to root_node
    GRAPH 'named_graph'
    RETURN e
```

Referencing the [SHORTEST_PATH](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-shortest-path.html) docs, we can start to break this down.

1. We are finding a path (the shortest path by the number of hops or "weight") from a "start" node to an "end" node.
2. Using `INBOUND` or `OUTBOUND` will depend on how your graph/data-model is built.
3. The `v,e` variables represent "vertices" and "edges" (`v` and `e`, respectively) found along the path.

This query pattern can then be used to calculate the number of vertices or edges, like so:

```
FOR start_node in child_collection
    FOR root_node IN root_collection
        LET edges = (
            FOR v,e IN INBOUND SHORTEST_PATH start_node to root_node
                GRAPH 'named_graph'
                RETURN e._id
        )
        RETURN {
            root: root_node._id,
            child: start_node._id,
            pathLen: LENGTH(paths)
        }
```

This may be a bit basic (there are likely ways to optimize this), but it shows how you can use a variable to hold a sub-query, using those results to calculate a path length.

Alternately, you can use [K_SHORTEST_PATHS](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-kshortest-paths.html) to do this calculation for you.  For instance, the previous query could be reduced to this:

```
FOR p IN INBOUND K_SHORTEST_PATHS start_node to root_node
    GRAPH 'named_graph'
    OPTIONS { weightAttribute: 'weight' }
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN p
```

Which finds the first shortest path between two points.  Here, we use `LIMIT 1` to make sure we only return one path.  The result will be something like:

```json
[
  {
    edges: [ ... ],
    vertices: [ ... ],
    weight: <number>
  }
]
```

Or you can customize the return to better meet your needs.  Do not return data you don't need or won't use.